# Contact manifolds and pseudodifferential operators

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, contact-geometry, pseudo-differential-operators

By way of background, I am currently trying to understand the theory of pseudodifferential operators in the context of contact geometry. I have some knowledge of pseudodifferential operators on compact manifolds, but almost no knowledge on contact geometry. I outline some questions below, and I would really appreciate any help I can get. This is mainly a reference request.

Consider a compact contact manifold $M$ of dimension $2n + 1$ with Reeb vector field $\xi$ and associated metric $g$ such that $\langle \xi, \xi\rangle \equiv 1$. Let $\Delta$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$. Are the following results true, and if yes, I would really appreciate some references:

1. $\Delta - \xi^2$ is subelliptic with loss of one derivative.
2. Operators of the form $\Delta - \xi^2 - i\alpha\xi$ are subelliptic outside a discrete set of numbers $\alpha$. Is it known whether such operators need to be positive semidefinite for a range of $\alpha$?
3. How much of a restriction is it to assume the existence of a constant length Killing field on a contact manifold? Are there lots of such examples, or are they rare?

Comment: What is the deffinition of the Laplace-Beltrami operator? Does your manifold has some Riemannian metric? If so, does it satisfy some compatibility condition with the contact structure (e. g. is M a Sassakian manifold)?